# Python: request to website doesn't work in any cases

Tags: python, request, yahoo-finance

I want to write a function which collects data from yahoo finance site. The website request looks like that:

```
import requests
def yahoo_summary_stats(stock):
    response = requests.get(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}")
    print(response.reason)
```

if I call the function with parameter 'ALB':

```
yahoo_summary_stats('ALB')
```

everything works fine and the request is ok. He correctly leads me to:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ALB

The call:

```
yahoo_summary_stats('AEE')
```

on other hand should lead me to the site https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AEE, which I can call without any problems in firefox.

The program for some reason gives me a 'Not found' error. What is the problem of my request to that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set User-Agent in headers...

```
def yahoo_summary_stats(stock):
    response = requests.get(f"http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}", headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.reason)

yahoo_summary_stats('ALB')
yahoo_summary_stats('AEE')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but for some reason I don't get the html-tags with this access e.g. as I would get with call yahoo_summary_stats('ALB') and without header ''<p class="D(ib) Va(t)" data-reactid="23"> ''

Comment: I wrote a new question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120640/python-request-to-website-doesnt-gives-the-html-i-need-in-any-cases).