# Python: request to website doesn't gives the html I need in any cases

Tags: python, html, python-requests, request-headers

Based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116360/python-request-to-website-doesnt-work-in-any-cases/70116782#70116782) I have some further question with requests on website finance.yahoo.com.

My request without User-Agent request gives me the html code I want to collect some data from the website.

The call with 'ALB' as parameter works fine, I get the requested data:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
def yahoo_summary_stats(stock):
    response = requests.get(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}")
    #response = requests.get(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}", headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('p', {'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'})

    sector = table.findAll('span')[1].text
    industry = table.findAll('span')[3].text
    print(f"{stock}: {sector}, {industry}")
    return sector, industry

web.yahoo_summary_stats('ALB')
```

Output:

```
ALB: Basic Materials, Specialty Chemicals
```

The call `yahoo_summary_stats('AEE')` doesnt work this way, so I need to acitivate headers to request the site with success.

But now with parameter`headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'}` the code doesn't work and he cannot find the paragraph p with class `'D(ib) Va(t)'`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It may be that these pages are generated (in part) with Javascript. If that's the case, BeautifulSoup may well "miss" the item(s) you're looking for. It could also be the case that paragraphs with those classes don't exist for every stock. Try __selenium__ whenever working with Javascript based websites.

Comment: first you should check in browser if you can see page when you turn off JavaScript (and reload page), Next you could display `response.text` to see if you don't get warning for bots/spamers/hackers/etc. - it may inform that page need cookies or JavaScript or send you `ReCaptcha`. And third: check if both pages use the same classes, etc. Some server may use different (random) classes for different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are fetching the wrong URL

```py
response = requests.get(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}/profile?p={stock}", headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})
```

Changing to above URL along with `user-agent` would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This page uses `JavaScript` to display information but `requests`,`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

But checking page in web browser without JavaScript I see this information on subpage `Profile`.

```
"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}/profile?p={stock}"
```

Code can get it for both `stock` from this page. But it needs `User-Agent` from real browser (or at least short version `'Mozilla/5.0'`

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

def yahoo_summary_stats(stock):

    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}/profile?p={stock}"

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    print('url:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('p', {'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'})

    sector = table.findAll('span')[1].text
    industry = table.findAll('span')[3].text

    print(f"{stock}: {sector}, {industry}")

    return sector, industry

# --- main ---

result = yahoo_summary_stats('ALB')
print('result:', result)

result = yahoo_summary_stats('AEE')
print('result:', result)
```

Result:

```
url: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ALB/profile?p=ALB
ALB: Basic Materials, Specialty Chemicals
result: ('Basic Materials', 'Specialty Chemicals')

url: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AEE/profile?p=AEE
AEE: Utilities, Utilities—Regulated Electric
result: ('Utilities', 'Utilities—Regulated Electric')
```